# Azure WebJob found, but timer functions are not getting executed

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I've done over 30 test runs, where I WAS able to get one work successfully (where it just did both a `Console.WriteLine("")` and a `(TextWriter)log.WriteLine("")`), but since trying to add in my real code, I'm not able to get it to work again.

I've stripped out all of the custom code that I added, and have it back to just doing logging statements, but Azure never finishes the initial job run.

Here's the entire output, no matter how long I let it sit:

> [08/16/2018 00:43:38 > 0708fc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
>
> [08/16/2018 00:43:40 > 0708fc: SYS INFO] Run script 'BatchJobEngineWebJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>
> [08/16/2018 00:43:40 > 0708fc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>
> [08/16/2018 00:43:43 > 0708fc: INFO] Found the following functions:
>
> [08/16/2018 00:43:43 > 0708fc: INFO] BatchJobEngineWebJob.Functions.DivisionI
>
> [08/16/2018 00:43:45 > 0708fc: INFO] Job host started

Reading the log, you can see that it's recognizing my timed function (called *.Functions.DivisionI), but that's it. It says the job host started, and that's it.

Here's the program.cs code where I configure everything:

```
static void Main()
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    //config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    //config.Queues.VisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    //config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
    config.JobActivator = new BatchJobActivator(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
    config.UseTimers();

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }

    var host = new JobHost(config);
    
    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    // Optional: Setup your configuration:
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
    
    // add any interfaces that will be needed here
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<IBatchJobService, BatchJobService>();
    // ...stripped the rest of the interfaces

    // executes the job
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ExecuteBatchJobs, ExecuteBatchJobs>();

    // One more thing - tell azure where your azure connection strings are
    var connStringDashboard = configuration["ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsDashboard"];
    var connStringStorage = configuration["ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsStorage"];

    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsDashboard", connStringDashboard);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage", connStringStorage);
}
```

And here's my Functions.cs class that contains the function that needs executed:

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly IBatchJobService _batchJobService;

    //public Functions(IBatchJobService batchJobService)
    //{
    //    _batchJobService = batchJobService;
    //}

    // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
    // on an Azure Queue called queue.
    //public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
    //{
    //    log.WriteLine(message);
    //}

    //[FunctionName("HourlyBatchJobs_DivisionI")]
    public async Task DivisionI([TimerTrigger("1 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
    {
        await log.WriteLineAsync("bout time!");
        Console.WriteLine("starting");
        //log.WriteLine("executing HourleyBatchJobs_DivisionI");
        //await _batchJobService.Execute();
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code here that could be stopping this from executing?

One thing to note: I've added and deleted over 40 jobs to my WebJobs list trying to get this to work. I've notived a very bad bug with Azure WebJobs. If I add, run, and delete a job, named "Test5". Then come back later and add another job with the same name, clicking the "Run" button will fail, saying the job is already executing. I end up having to add the job as Test5b to allow it to run. I'm wondering if this is potentially screwing something up not allowing all of these successive tests to fail.

Comment: Just a guess, but doesn't the function (and class) need to be static?

Comment: @SimplyGed changed the function class, as well as my "DivisionI" methods both to static and still get the same result

Comment: I have seen WebJobs that died refuse to exit gracefully. Can you go look in your SCM site under processes and see if there are WebJob processes that are lingering that shouldn't be?

Comment: @RobReagan I believe only 2. I went to {WebApp} => Process Explorer under the monitoring section on the left pane. It only showed 2 w3wp threads.

Comment: My only other ideas are to increase the timer interval in your TimerTrigger, and also to attempt deploying to a freshly provisioned Web App instance.

Comment: @RobReagan Will definitely do that (trigger). What's a "freshly provisioned" instance? Basically a new deployment that restarts iis?

Comment: I'd create a brand new Azure Web App that has never had anything deployed to it. Then I'd deploy the WebJob. This will ensure that you do not have any previous installations or web applications influencing your WebJob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the VS 2017 tooling for .Net Core webjobs does not exist yet, although it is planed.It's still possible to write a Core based WebJob and deploy it manually to your Web App. But do note that the WebJob SDK (which is a whole other topic) does not yet support .NET Core. You could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/98).

Also, you could use **.net core 2.0 console application** to achieve it. You could refer to the following steps.

1.Install [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/3.0.0-beta5) package.

2.Add the following code in the `Program.cs` file.

```
var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

if (config.IsDevelopment)
{
     config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
}
config.UseTimers();
config.DashboardConnectionString ="storage connectionstring";
config.StorageConnectionString = "storage connectionstring";
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

3.Add the `Functions.cs` file to the project.

```
public class Functions
 {
      public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("timer job fired!");
        }
  }
```

4.The output on KUDU.
[image]